# reform array with only 1 key

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ecmascript-6

Working with some data from a JSON/Array from a known video game. I'm close to creating a new array with ONLY the localized name, but can't quite get it right. What am I missing:

```
const endpoint = './heroes-org.json'
let heroes = []
let renamed = []

fetch(endpoint)
  .then(text => text.json())
  .then(data => heroes.push(...data.result.heroes))
  .then(() => {
    for(i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++){
        // renamed += heroes[i].localized_name
        //heroes.map(function){
        //}
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(renamed)
        }, 2000)
    }})
```

The map function was an idea to get rid of the unnecessary keys of each array element.

Also, if I just console log `heroes` from within the chrome console shows me this:

[image]

Doesn't seem quite right. Why is my array separated into 0-99 etc.?

I ultimately want to end up with just 1 array containing all the 115 heroes' names.

Comment: That actually is just a single array, the chrome console has spit it up for you (purely visual).  It will still function as a single array.  Notice the length property: 115.

Comment: Don't worry. This is a chrome thing. Your array is fine, but chrome separates elements in sections of 100 so it's not too much info at once

Comment: Why has this been closed? The restructured array in Chrome was only an aside to the original question which asks how to remap the heroes array to just an array of localized names. Admittedly, that has also been answered numerous times on SO, but the link that was provided above is *not* an answer to the question.

Comment: @Helle - you can solve your data remapping either by: `renamed.push(heroes[i].localized_name);` inside the existing loop **OR** `renamed = heroes.map(hero => hero.localized_name);` *instead of* the loop.

Comment: @Raith When using the first option you provided, I see that the console spits out 112 records, each indicating that each name has been added to the array. So once complete, the console shows me 112 arrays with 112 names in it. Is this normal, or should I only show one array in the console once the operation is completed? The second option with `renamed = heroes.map.....` works as intented and shows me ONE array once completed. Thank you

Comment: Yes sorry. The answer that I was writing explained in more detail but I cannot post it because this question has been closed (wrongly IMO). So please do take that setTimeout OUT of the loop! Log the array AFTER the loop. Then both solutions should give identical results.

Comment: Your question got closed because people focussed on your second point about how the array appears broken up in debug console. It was fair to mention it but it took focus away from the issue you were having creating the array of names. Be careful not to conflate multiple issues in the future.

Comment: Last point. It is always nicer to use Array.map than to write your own loop to do the same. But the syntax I gave you used a "fat arrow function" which might not be compatible with your JavaScript environment. If that's the case then simply use the older uglier syntax... `renamed = heroes.map(function (hero) { return hero.localized_name; });` and be sure to [learn how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a feature of Chrome. Chrome breaks up an array into smaller parts consisting of 100 elements for easier debugging. Look at length property, it's value is 115 :)